Bounded solutions of nonlinear third-order ODEs
I am interested in understanding the behavior of solutions to certain nonlinear third-order ODEs. Specifically, I am curious about conditions that guarantee all solutions remain bounded for $t \in [0, +\infty) $.
To provide some background, consider the following examples of linear ODEs:

$ x' = -x $
$ x'' = -x $

The solutions to both of these equations are bounded on $[0, +\infty) $. Intuitively, the negative sign on the right-hand side acts as a "negative feedback mechanism," pulling the solutions back towards the origin when they become too large.
Conversely, if we change the sign:

$ x' = x $
$ x'' = x $

We can easily see that these equations have unbounded solutions on $ [0, +\infty) $.
However, this intuition does not always hold. For instance, consider the third-order linear ODE:
$$ x''' = -x $$
Despite the negative feedback, the general solution includes terms that grow without bound as $ t \to +\infty $.
My question is:
Can this phenomenon be extended to nonlinear ODEs? Specifically, does there exist a function $ f(x) $ such that the nonlinear third-order ODE:
$$ x''' = -f(x) $$
has all its solutions bounded for $ t \in [0, +\infty) $?
I am aware that my familiarity with techniques for handling nonlinear ODEs is limited, and I would greatly appreciate any insights or references that could help address this problem. Understanding this could have significant implications for the study of dynamical systems and stability analysis.
Thank you in advance for your help!
This question was initially posted in MO (link: Bounded solutions of nonlinear third-order ODEs), but people there suggested me to post it in MSE first.

One property of these systems is that no linearly stable fixed point can exist since the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\0&0&1\\alpha&0&0\end{pmatrix}$ cannot have eigenvalues with all negative real parts for any real value of $\alpha$.

I think I have a partial answer to rule out the suspicious case that $f >0$ on $(0,\infty)$ and $f< 0$ on $(-\infty,0)$.
First, let $f\in C(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$, consider a solution  $x:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ of the IVP
$$
x'''(t)=-f(x(t)), \quad x(0)=c_0, ~ x'(0)=c_1, ~ x''(0)=c_2,
$$
and assume that $x$ is bounded. Then $x'''$ is bounded.

We show that $x'$ and $x''$ are bounded: By Taylor's Theorem we get for $t \ge 1$:
$$
(1)  \quad x(t-1)=x(t) - x'(t) + \frac{x''(t)}{2} -  \frac{x'''(\xi(t))}{6},
$$
and
$$
(2) \quad x(t+1)=x(t) + x'(t) + \frac{x''(t)}{2} +  \frac{x'''(\eta(t))}{6}.
$$
Now $(1)+(2)$ and $(1)-(2)$ show that $x''$ and $x'$ are bounded on $[1,\infty)$, hence $x''$ and $x'$ are bounded on $[0,\infty)$.

Set
$$
F(s):=\int_0^s f(\sigma)d\sigma \quad (s \in \mathbb{R}).  
$$
From $x'''(t)=-f(x(t))$ we get for $t \in [0,\infty)$:
$$
x'''(t)x'(t)=-f(x(t))x'(t) \Rightarrow \int_0^t x'''(\tau)x'(\tau)d\tau= - F(x(t))+F(c_0)
$$
$$
\Rightarrow \left[x''(\tau)x'(\tau)\right]_0^t - \int_0^t (x''(\tau))^2 d\tau
=F(c_0)-F(x(t))
$$
$$
\Rightarrow x''(t)x'(t)-c_2c_1 - \int_0^t (x''(\tau))^2 d\tau
=F(c_0)-F(x(t)).
$$
Hence we have
$$
(3) \quad x''(t)x'(t) + F(x(t)) = c_2c_1 + F(c_0) +\int_0^t (x''(\tau))^2 d\tau.
$$
This shows that $t \mapsto x''(t)x'(t) + F(x(t))$ is increasing and that $(x'')^2 \in L^1([0, \infty))$. Since $(x'')^2$ is Lipschitz continuous (as $2x''x'''$ is bounded) we get $(x''(t))^2 \to 0$ $(t \to \infty)$, hence
$$
x''(t) \to 0 \quad (t \to \infty).
$$
At this point we know
$$
(4) \quad c_2c_1 + F(c_0) \le x''(t)x'(t) + F(x(t)) = x''(t)x'(t) + \int_0^{x(t)} f(\sigma) d\sigma
$$

We now choose $c_0,c_1,c_2$  such that $c:=c_2c_1 + F(c_0)>0$. Then $(4)$ yields that $x$ is not oscillating: As $x''(t)x'(t) \to 0$ $(t \to \infty)$ there is some $t_0 > 0$ such that
$$
0<\frac{c}{2}<F(x(t))=\int_0^{x(t)} f(\sigma) d\sigma \quad  (t \ge t_0).
$$
In particular there is some $\delta > 0$ such that
$$
x(t) \ge \delta ~ (t \ge t_0) ~~ \text{or} ~~ x(t) \le -\delta ~ (t \ge t_0).
$$

Now, if in addition $f >0$ on $(0,\infty)$ and $f< 0$ on $(-\infty,0)$ then there is some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that for $t \ge t_0$
$$
x(t) \ge \delta \Rightarrow f(x(t)) \ge \varepsilon \Rightarrow x'''(t)\le - \varepsilon,
$$
then $x(t) \to - \infty$ $(t \to \infty)$, or
$$
x(t) \le -\delta \Rightarrow f(x(t)) \le -\varepsilon \Rightarrow x'''(t)\ge  \varepsilon,
$$
then $x(t) \to \infty$ $(t \to \infty)$, a contradiction


Note that this method also rules out some other cases. Since $c$ can be chosen arbitrarily large there are unbounded solutions of $x'''=-f(x)$ if $F$ is bounded above on $\mathbb{R}$. For example $x'''=-\sin(x)$ has unbounded solutions.

To answer your question, I think we can consider the [Lyapunov function][1] (which is generally used sort of like pinpoint for testing the boundedness of solutions in non-linear system and apply it to your question. So, let us first define:
$$V(x,x',x'')=\frac{1}{2}(x'')^2+\frac{1}{2}(x')^2+\frac{g(x)}{2}$$
and let us find its derivative:
$$
\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{x}}x'+\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{x'}}x''+\frac{\partial{V}}{x''}x'''
$$
$$
\frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{1}{2}g'(x), \quad \frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{x'}}=x', \quad \frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{x''}}=x''
$$
So we will have:
$$
\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{1}{2}g'(x)x'+x'x''+x''x'''
$$
We can substitute $-f(x)$ at $x'''$ such that:
$$
\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{1}{2}g'(x)x'+x'x''-x''f(x)
$$
Now, since $g(x)$ hasn't been defined yet, let us $g(x)=x^2$, thus having $g'(x)=2x$. Subsequently, we need to define an exact form for $f(x)$, let's suppose $f(x)=kx+bx^3$. It will all become:
$$
\frac{dV}{dt}=xx'+x'x''-x''(kx+bx^3)
$$
$$
\frac{dV}{dt} = xx'+x'x''-kxx''-bx^3x''
$$
$$
\frac{dV}{dt}=x'x-kx'x''+x'x''-bx^3x''
$$
After this, we need to analyse the sign. Let $k=1$, therefore having:
$$
\frac{dV}{dt}=x'x-bx^3x''
$$
$$
\frac{dV}{dt}=x'x(1-bx^2)
$$
So for the sign it will be:
$$
x'x(1-bx^2)\leq 0
$$
$$
1-bx^2\leq 0 \quad \text{for}\quad x\neq 0
$$
Thus leading us to:
$$
bx^2\ge 1
$$
This set the basis. It will likely need to be further advanced considering each single term or potentially using the LaSalle's invariance principle. Tell me if you want me to go much more in depth. I wish you a good day!
[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_function

Inspired by whpowell96's comment, I can only give a partial answer, involving a stability and not directly a boundedness argument. Nevertheless, as you will see, this stability (or better the instability) analysis of the given equation at least gives possibly some indications on the properties the right side $f$ must have in order to hope to get bounded solutions.
(Un)Stability of the solutions of the equation $x^{\prime\prime\prime} = -f(x)$.
If $f\in C^{0,1}$ in a neighbourhood of $x=0$, and moreover $x=0$ is a isolated zero for it, then the null solution of the ODE under analysis is unstable.
This result has been proved by Aimé Huaux [1] and then was extended to the general $n$-th order ODE
$$
x^{(n)} = f(x)\quad n\in\Bbb N
$$
by Wolf Dietrich Müller in [1]. A description of the work of this last Author is given by Conti, Reissig and Sansone in their monograph [3] (§1.1, pp. 40-44).
They start by proving the assertion in the case $f\in C^2$ and $\alpha=f^\prime (0)\neq 0$ by using a classical theorem of Ioèl Gil’evich Malkin ([3], §2.2.1, pp. 162-173) and applying it to its first order equivalent system of ODEs ([3], §1.1, pp. 41-42)
$$\label{1}\tag{1}
\begin{cases}
x^\prime = y\\
y^\prime = z\\
z^\prime = -f(y)
\end{cases}.
$$
In performing that step they evaluate the eigenvalues of the matrix
$$\label{2}\tag{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\alpha & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix} 
$$
which are exactly the solutions of the cyclotomic equation $\lambda^3+\alpha=0$. And since, irrespective of the sign of $\alpha$, at least one of the solutions of this equations has a positive real part, the system is always unstable.
After having dealt with the particular case above, they proceed in proving the general case, assuming $f\in C^{0,1}$ ([3], §1.1, pp. 43-44) and then applying a theorem on the instability of autonomous dynamical systems due to Krasovskii ([3], §1.1, pp. 40-41).
(Possibly) Necessary conditions for the boundedness of the solutions
The instability theorem above in general defines only locally the behaviour of the system \eqref{1}, thus even if it proves the effective instability of it in a neighbourhood of $x=0$, nothing can be said on the boundedness of its solutions. Nevertheless, basing on this result, something more can be said on the structure that $f$ should have in order to allow bounded solutions for \eqref{1}.

$f$ must have more than one single isolated zero, for otherwise it is possible to extend the construction of Krasovskii ([3], §1.1, pp. 40-41) to the whole $\Bbb R$ not only to a neighbourhood of $x=0$, and this implies the unboundedness of the trajectories of \eqref{1}
$f$ cannot have only isolated zeros. Intuitively this is due to the fact that each isolated singular point act as a 3-dimensional repelling focus and this does not evidently guarantee boundedness of the solutions.

As a final consideration, it seems plausible that in order for the equation $x^{\prime\prime\prime} = -f(x)$ to have only bounded solution, the vanishing of the vector field $f$ outside a compact set should be required: however, this is only a guess that should be verified by further analysis. Well, my two cents.
Reference
[1] Aimé Huaux, "Instabilität der Ruhelagen für gewisse Differentialgleichungen" (German), Zeitschrift für Angewandte Mathematik und Mechanik (ZAMM) 44, Sonderheft, T33-T34 (1964), MR185211, Zbl 0139.04004.
[2] Wolf Dietrich Müller, "Zum Nachweis der Instabilität der Ruhelagen bei gewissen Differentialgleichungen" (German), Zeitschrift für Angewandte Mathematik und Mechanik (ZAMM) 45, 359-360 (1965), Zbl 0137.28703.
[3] Rolf Reissig, Giovanni Sansone, Roberto Conti, Non-linear differential equations of higher order, [Original edition published in 1969] (English), Monographs and Textbooks on Pure and Applied Mathematics. Leyden: Noordhoff International Publishing. XIII, 669 (1974), MR344556, Zbl 0275.34001.
